# Why are animated gifs so slow on my LAN?

Tags: animated-gif

Whenever I load a [page with animated gifs](http://www.buzzfeed.com/lyapalater/animals-that-are-huge-jerks), they start out playing really, really slow, almost like the computer is taking its time to load each frame individually.  I've checked that the same problem exists in Firefox, IE and Chrome, and exists on several of the computers of my LAN (I haven't checked every single one).

After the browser "loads" all the frames, the animated gif will play normally.  It seems like it won't play right until it is cached.

Can I fix this?

Comment: Well, what you're observing is pretty much exactly what's happening. The browser loads the image, the image is made up of individual frames, so you only see the frames that were loaded so far.

Comment: That example page is full of junk, so you have to wait for most of it to finish loading.  Try accessing one of the pictures [diiectly](http://s3-ec.buzzfed.com/static/enhanced/webdr01/2013/2/22/11/anigif_enhanced-buzz-4290-1361549248-28.gif), it's a little faster. But as Oliver points out, that's just the way it is. What makes you think it's any slower on your LAN than another?

Comment: Over on StackOverflow: [Why do animated gif images take so long to load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872996/why-do-animated-gif-images-take-so-long-to-load)

Comment: If you do a [basic Google search](http://www.google.ca/search?q=animated+gif+slow+to+load), you'll find it not just you. :)

Comment: Yep. Nothing to fix. It's just a matter of the way things work.

Comment: @techie007 - I've read in the stack exchange sites that it is okay to ask a question that you might ask on Google.  Besides, I came here to get answers.  I've already googled.

Comment: I'm glad someone downvoted me without telling me why.  What's wrong with my question?

Comment: @techie007 - if you repeat your comment as an answer, I am willing to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That example page is full of junk, so you have to wait for most of it to finish loading. Try accessing one of the pictures [directly](http://s3-ec.buzzfed.com/static/enhanced/webdr01/2013/2/22/11/anigif_enhanced-buzz-4290-1361549248-28.gif), it's a little faster.

But as Oliver points out in his comment, that's just the way it is with Gifs.

More info over on StackOverflow: [Why do animated gif images take so long to load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872996/why-do-animated-gif-images-take-so-long-to-load)

Comment: I don't know that it is only slow on my LAN - it just didn't seem right to me.